# Reading \n from stdin with read()

Tags: c, newline, stdin

I wanna read a string from stdin, which will contain multiple lines, separated by \n's, but the problem is that if I try to read the string from stdin iterating through all the chars like so:

```
char buff;
while(read(0, &buff, 1) > 0)
     foo(buff);
```

it's reading a string like "hello\n" as having the chars `h-e-l-l-o-\-n` and not the new line at the end as a char. How do I fix that?

Comment: You fix that by fixing your input. Newline, in ASCII, is 0x0a. If you're reading something with "n" (0x6e) in it, your input is broken, not your program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `'\n'` escape sequence is interpreted by the compiler. Entering it on the keyboard or reading it from a file does not produce a newline character: you literally get back the two characters from the input - first the slash, then the lowercase `'n'` character.

If you enter an end-of-line character, press <kbd>Enter</kbd> on the keyboard, or add an end-of-line character to your input file.

Comment: so if I wanna be able to use \n as new line then I have to look for the sequence of the 2 chars \ and n?

Comment: Just cause the user will be responsible for input so I wanna leave as little room for errors as possible

Comment: @dietbacon Right, if you would like to treat escape sequences as special characters, you need to write a little code to process it yourself. Fortunately, this is not too hard an exercise: look for a single backslash, set an `escape` flag, and run a `switch` on the character that follows to interpret the sequence as `\n`, `\r`, `\t`, and so on.